# Spring OpenApi generator do not import Set which is used in generated interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

OpenApi generator is used to create Api interfaces. I use `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.6.0`. It generates code where Set is one of method parameters, but generator do not add `java.util.Set` to import.

In method bellow I want to get set of unique countries which user has chosen. Here you can see `Set<String> countryList` , but there is no `import java.util.Set` or even `import java.util.*`.
Here is that generated API method:

```
import com.example.test.model.ErrorResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameters;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ArraySchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import jakarta.annotation.Generated;

@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-07-14T10:05:08.694721+03:00[Europe/Riga]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "application", description = "the application API")
public interface ApplicationApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Operation(
        operationId = "applicationApplicationIdCountriesPost",
        summary = "Lets a user to enter his countries",
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Succesfully added countries to {applicationId}"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation error", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "*/*", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal error")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/application/{applicationId}/country",
        produces = { "*/*" },
        consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Void> applicationApplicationIdTaxliabilityPost(
        @Parameter(name = "applicationId", description = "ID of application", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("applicationId") Long applicationId,
        @Parameter(name = "countryList", description = "Country list in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2", required = true) @Valid @RequestPart(value = "countryList", required = true) Set<String> countryList
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
}
```

Here is yaml where from it is generated:

```
  '/application/{applicationId}/country':
    post:
      summary: Lets a user to enter his countries
      operationId: applicationApplicationIdCountriesPost
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/applicationId_pathParam'
        - name: countryList
          in: formData
          description: Country list in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2
          type: array
          minItems: 1
          maxItems: 3
          uniqueItems: true
          items:
            type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Succesfully added countries to {applicationId}'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/responses/400'
        '500':
          $ref: '#/responses/500'
```

And openApi gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}



def apiPackageFolder = 'com.example.test.api'
def modelPackageFolder = 'com.example.test.model'

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("${projectDir}/specs/test.yaml")
    outputDir.set("${projectDir}/src/main/java-generated")
    apiPackage.set("${apiPackageFolder}")
    modelPackage.set("${modelPackageFolder}")
    configOptions = [
            useSpringBoot3: "true",
            openApiNullable: "false",
            useOptional: "true",
            "interfaceOnly" : "true",
            sourceFolder: ""
    ]
}
compileJava.dependsOn tasks.openApiGenerate
```

I've tryed to add to openApiGenerate `importMappings.put("java.util.List","java.util.*")` as a hack.

Comment: Hi, please make sure your yaml input is valid. OpenAPI generator validates it before generation, but you can also use e.g. editor-next.swagger.io . If the problems still happens, please post your valid input yaml.

Comment: @gluwak, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @some_user have not found solution.